# Image processing

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I have several bitmaps images and want to segment and access the position (and want know the size) of the continuous tone very high correlated areas,I mean by continues tone areas (high correlated segments) only the the areas that hold the exact same values of pixels. I have experience in image processing and am using c++ and opencv but i didnt find a library doing that am afraid if I do the programming I will lose the performance and the calculation became inefficient while I need to process further a lot of things.  in this time but due to 10 years of this science leaving I became clumsy and I cant find the answers as I were young, I will be grateful if you help me in any ideas about that because am stuck. thanks for the kind reading and help.

Comment: I think you are probably looking for *Blob Analysis*, or *Connected Components Analysis*. Failing that, you could do some *neighbourhood operations* to fnd the mean of a neighbourhood area, then subtract each pixel from the mean of its neighbours, since where a pixel equals the mean of its neighbours the result of subtraction will be a black pixel, then threshold that very low and invert so that your areas of interest are white.

Answer (score 1):

I can demonstrate the concept of my comment using ImageMagick, and this test image which has the useful property of being noise which means you can see it on SO's white background and the algorithm shouldn't see it.

[image]

I can average it over an area of 15x15 like this:

```
convert test.png -statistic mean 15x15 x.png
```

which gives this

[image]

then threshold and invert it so you can see the areas of continuous tone identified in white

```
convert test.png -statistic mean 15x15 test.png -compose difference -composite -depth 8 -threshold 1 -negate x.png
```

[image]

You can experiment with different widths and heights of the blurring box like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in 3 7 15 25; do
   for y in 3 7 15 25; do
     convert -label "${x}x${y}" test.png -statistic mean ${x}x${y} miff:-
   done
done | montage - -frame 5 -tile 4x out.png
```

which gives this:

[image]

and the corresponding masked image thus:

[image]

You can the pass that into the Connected Components Analysis like this:

```
convert test.png -statistic mean 5x5                   \
        test.png -compose difference -composite        \
        -depth 8 -threshold 1 -negate                  \
        -define connected-components:verbose=true      \
        -define connected-components:area-threshold=20 \
        -connected-components 8 -auto-level blobs.png
```

which will give you this which contains the coordinates of the blobs

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 500x500+0+0 270.8,271.7 177169 srgb(0,0,0)
  1: 216x216+52+41 159.5,148.5 46656 srgb(255,255,255)
  8: 114x114+63+351 119.5,407.5 10039 srgb(255,255,255)
  2: 81x100+354+47 394.0,96.5 8100 srgb(255,255,255)
  5: 49x49+348+204 372.0,228.0 2401 srgb(255,255,255)
  6: 358x5+55+287 233.5,289.0 1790 srgb(255,255,255)
  10: 45x45+244+383 265.9,405.0 1520 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 4x289+451+181 452.5,325.0 1156 srgb(255,255,255)
  7: 122x4+57+309 117.5,310.5 488 srgb(255,255,255)
  9: 4x114+416+356 417.5,412.5 456 srgb(255,255,255)
  4: 15x15+312+185 319.0,192.0 225 srgb(255,255,255)
```

I can then outline the detected areas on top of the original image:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your kind concern and deep explanation hope you all the best . but this is not what am exactly looking for while my objects are non uni formal, they are part of objects or even a background things, actually I need to extract the real high correlated areas but in  away that I can calculate the size and label them. and do more thanks for the kind efforts and GOD may bless you.